# ORA-02048 - Attempt to begin distributed transaction without loggin on

Tags: sql, oracle

anyone know something about this error?
ORA-02048: attempt to begin distributed transaction without logging on
ORA-02063: preceding line from ..dblink

It occurs when I invoke since Java a PL/SQL Package that contains dblinks to access to other database for insert data. The dblink works good with other clauses, but not in this Package.
If I invoke this PL/SQL Package since TOAD, it works good.

I'm trying to reproduce this error, and I see this error arises from a pattern:
When I click the button which makes the PL run, the log shows me an error "ora-02292 integrity constraint child record found", and the next time I click the button, appears the error "ORA-02048", it is like the first error did lose the connection with remote database.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a minimal testcase that demonstrates the problem, it's impossible to say.

```
However, looking up the error message:
-bash-4.1$ oerr ora 2048
02048, 00000, "attempt to begin distributed transaction without logging on"
// *Cause: client program must issue a distributed transaction login.
// *Action: contact support.
```

So, I'd recommend contacting Oracle support and opening an SR.  But, the first thing they're likely to ask for is a working test case that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot reproduce it. It is thrown in Production Environments in a process that treats records massively. For example 100 records are passed to this PL and it inserts this records like: 
1.- insert into mytable (..) values (..); 
2.- insert into mytable@dblink (..) values (..);
If I use the same parameters in Preproduccion environments I cannot obtain this error.
Please any idea?? like problems in the way that are configured the dblinks in the database? Exceeding max connections to the same dblink?

Comment: What (specific) version of Oracle?  Are you running shared server?  I really don't think you have any choice but to open an SR.

Comment: Oracle version is: Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.7.0 - 64bit Production, and server is dedicated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was thatI have different procedures, like that:

procedure1 -> (call) -> procedure 2 -> (call) -> procedure3

In procedure3 I have a clausure with dblink that insert into a remote table.

Procedure1 catchs the exceptions that may occur in procedure 2 and procedure3.

The problem is when an exception is throw in procedure3. In this case the rollback placed in the exception catch of procedure1, should finish the transaction, but it isn't working as I expected. The transaction is this case remains open and the second time in the procedure executions, oracle shows me the ORA-02048 error.

The solution was moving the exception catch into procedure3.